# Convert a List of Object to Map<String,String> using jdk 8 lambdas

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I want to convert a `List<Properies>` to a `Map<String,String>` using jdk 8 lambdas without doing a for loop. The map should contain the key as SubProperty.name and value as Properties.value.

```
public class Properties
{
    private SubProperty subProperty;

    private String value;

    public SubProperty getSubProperty()
    {
        return subProperty;
    }

    public void setSubProperty(SubProperty subProperty)
    {
        this.subProperty = subProperty;
    }

    public String getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class SubProperty
{
    private String category;
    private String name;

    public String getCategory()
    {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category)
    {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because: it looks like basic stream excercise which suggest homework assignment, but ["3. Questions asking for homework help must include a **summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem**, and a **description of the difficulty you are having** solving it."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Current state of your question doesn't fulfill these requirements. Use [edit] option to improve it.

Comment: Also read this [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6166)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions i did the same thing in eclipse but not sure why does it shows me only the Object methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
List<Properties> properties = ...
Map<String, String> map = properties.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(prop -> prop.getSubProperty().getName(), prop -> prop.getValue()));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you construct a `Map` from a `Stream` using `Collectors.toMap()`, you must consider whether your `Stream` may contain duplicate keys. In your case duplicate keys mean multiple `Properties` instances having `SubProperty` with the same name.

To resolve duplicates, you can use the 3 argument variant of `Collectors.toMap`. For example, the following will choose one of the `getValue()` values when encountering duplicate keys:

```
Map<String,String> map = 
    list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getSubProperty().getName(),
                                  Properties::getValue,
                                  (v1,v2) -> v1));
```

Another option is to use `Collectors.groupingBy`, which would group the values that share the same key into a `List`:

```
Map<String,List<String>> map = 
    list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getSubProperty().getName(),
                                       Collectors.mapping(Properties::getValue,
                                                          Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: The Collector created by Collectors.toMap throws `IllegalStateException` if an attempt is made to store a key that already exists in the Map. If you want to collect items in a Map and if you expect duplicate entries in the source, you should use `Collectors.toMap(Function, Function, BinaryOperator)` method. That's the right and complete answer.

Comment: @AlexMamo *unless* you know u will not have duplicates, and in case you will you *want* that exception...